# flutter bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create the line above the selected item I tried some different approaches but I'm new to using the original bottom nav bar instead of packages

[image]

I have the following thing implemented, as you can see everything is is good except the line I want.

[image]

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DashboardScreen> createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: const Color(0xFF161E21), // Background color
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          unselectedFontSize: 14,
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFF00A8A8), // Selected item color
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white, // Unselected item color
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 0 ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/selectedHome.svg') : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
              label: 'الرئيسية',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 1 ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/selectedTools.svg') : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/tools.svg'),
              label: 'الصيانة',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 2 ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/selectedCharge.svg') : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/charge.svg'),
              label: 'الشحن',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: _selectedIndex == 3 ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/selectedCar.svg') : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/car.svg'),
              label: 'المركبات',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have two separate questions here. You could create a another question for this with better definition what is the problem "I was wondering if there is a better way to navigate between pages instead of indices, I'm using GetX". 

For the first problem you could try to create your own icon widget because they are just widgets. Check this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem/icon.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a good approach in the "Write your first Flutter app" tutorial, in particular in section 7 of the codelab!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).